# JavaScript: “Access Denied” and “Object doesn't support this property or method” errors

Tags: jquery, ajaxcontroltoolkit, thickbox

I’m working on an application that uses the ajax control toolkit 1.0.20229.0, jquery 1.3.2 and thickbox 3.

We are in the process of removing the ajax control toolkit, but since it’s a large app it will take several versions before we can completely remove it.

When I click a link that pops up a thickbox modal containing iframe it works, most of the time. In IE7 I sometimes get either “Access Denied” or “Object doesn’t support this property or method” it seemingly random, but the errors always seem to be happening in the ajax control toolkit javascript.

Has anyone seen this before or have any suggestions on how to track it down?

Comment: could you post the relevant code?

Comment: Not easily, the code that's failing is in the ajavax control toolkit, all I've done is to hook them to some html. I'm working on as small an example as is possible. I'm hoping that I may find the bug in the process.

Answer (score 3):

"Access is denied" usually comes when there is cross domain referencing. Check if you are some how referencing any page from a different domain than the one which is running your jQuery. Ajax Control Toolkit itself does not do cross domain referencing.

Comment: Is there a way to allow this happen? My page tries to access currency exchange rate feed information from another server and comes up with this error... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This **sounds** like your browser is trying to access the dom before its ready.

Are you wrapping your javascript in a (jQuery example)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ...do your stuff here ...});
```

?

That would be the first thing I'd try.

Comment: That or the control library simply isn't being loaded.

Comment: It's not my code that's being called, it's the stuff in the ajax control toolkit.

Comment: or the iframe access would be x-domain